# RazorEngine strange compile exception

Tags: c#, razorengine

I have this template using RazorEngine v 3.4.1:

```
@{ var Title = Model.Page.Title ;
                   var Description = Model.Page.Description;
                   var Articles = Model.Site.Articles;
                   var SiteUrl = Model.Site.WebsiteUrl;
             }
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
 <title>@Title</title>
 <description>@Description</description>
 <link>@SiteUrl</link>
 <lastBuildDate>@DateTime.Now</lastBuildDate>
 <pubDate>@DateTime.Now</pubDate>

@foreach(var Article in Articles){
  <item>
    <title>@Article.Title</title>
    <description>@Article.Description</description>
    <link>@Article.Url</link>
    <guid>@Article.Url</guid>
    <pubDate>@Article.Date.ToString()</pubDate>
  </item>
}
</channel>
</rss>
```

When I try to compile it, it throws **TemplateParsingException** saying that:

> The "item" element was not closed.  All elements must be either
>   self-closing or have a matching end tag.

When I remove this line from template:

```
<link>@Article.Url</link>
```

it compiles just fine, without any problem and the result is as expected...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do the URLs look like? Any strange characters in them?

Comment: @henk yes, you're right. It would be a runtime error not compile time.

Comment: Could it be your use of the word Url -- although that would seem to be quite a limitation...

Comment: Notice that the line "<guid>@Article.Url</guid>" is not causing any trouble at all. But add "<link>@Article.Url</link>" and the exception occures.

Answer (score 1):

MS added support for HTML5 void elements in Razor 2, and this is why you are seeing this problem. The easiest solution is just to escape the tags so that Razor sees them as literals, i.e. @:

The full list of elements that this applies to are (taken from System.Web.Razor.Parser.HtmlMarkupParser)

```
    "area",
    "base",
    "br",
    "col",
    "command",
    "embed",
    "hr",
    "img",
    "input",
    "keygen",
    "link",
    "meta",
    "param",
    "source",
    "track",
    "wbr"
```

Comment: while I could not get `@:` to work, using @Raw("<link>") did work

Answer (score 1):

Razor checks HTML5 compatibility and link tag with content is **invalid** as it is void element.
More info about HTML void elements:
http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/syntax.html#void-element

> The following is a complete list of the void elements in HTML:
>
> area, base, br, col, command, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, wbr

Solution in RazorEngine **without using MVC Html Helpers like
@Html.Raw** is to add one of these:

```
@(new RazorEngine.Text.RawString("<link>" + Article.Url + "</link>"))

@Raw("<link>" + Article.Url + "</link>")
```

Additional if **you want to use syntax like @Html.Raw**, you could extend template syntax with your own class as in doc https://matthid.github.io/RazorEngine/TemplateBasics.html#Extending-the-template-Syntax